# VB6 convert label to bigger integer

Tags: vb6, integer, label, textfield

Is ther a way to expand a lable or a textfield. Not the size i mean the memory of the label or a text field.

My problem is that, when i add 1 to 300000 there is a stackoverfloat. Is ther a way to convert the text field to a long or a big integer ?

I hope you can help me to solve this problem :D

(Sorry for my broken English)

Answer (score 1):

Use the 32 bit `Long` type rather than the 16 bit (default) `Integer` type:

```
dim x as long
x = clng(textbox.text) '//convert to long (or val() for a more forgiving parse)

dim y as long 
y = x + 1 + 300000
```